# Why does Hoberman sphere open when thrown up?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag, aerodynamics, air

Please try and explain this to a dummy :) I haven’t had any university level physics education, at least yet.

I was messing around with a mega sphere (Hoberman sphere toy) at a family dinner when I noticed that I couldn’t explain why the closed sphere would open up when thrown up, but not when being dropped down. It was like something about giving it an upward initial force was critical for it to open.

If anyone has an understanding of the mechanics at play here I would love to here.

Comment: When you throw it up, do you add rotation to it?

Comment: Hi, to get useful answers here, please read the guidelines. in particular, describe the toy and provide a link to  the manufacturer's page or other location where we can learn about the object.

Comment: possibly useful:   https://wiki.physics.wisc.edu/facultywiki/Hoberman_Sphere#:~:text=Abstract%3A,that%20angular%20momentum%20is%20conserved.

Comment: And this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggi_6_8_fF0